# Nitrate fertilizer problem

Tags: homework, nitrogen-cycle, units

[image]

[image]

Take the above problem. I understand how to do the calculation. However I can't seem to understand the units of the answer in the calculation.

[image]

The answers illustrate the units as t/ha^-2 which is equivalent to t(ha)^2. But where do these units arise from? Crop yield is represented by tones per ha in the table above. So wouldn't total crop yield just be tones? I can't seem to find any intuition whatsoever as to why the units are t/ha^-2? Could someone please give me a hint or a solution?

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Accurately type the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a mistake in the provided solutions – it should say either $\mathrm{t/ha}$ or $\mathrm{t \, ha}^{-1}$. Furthermore, the answer should be multiplied with the area of fields.

There are two different quantities in this task: *yield* which is the mass of harvested crops (and has units $\mathrm{t}$), and *field yield* which is yield per unit of field area (which has units $\mathrm{t/ha}$). In the provided table, you are given *field yield*, but in the question, the farmer wants to have the highest *yield*.

The yield if fertilizer is put on one field will be:
$$m=7\;{\rm \frac{t}{ha}}\times 1\;{\rm ha}+3\;{\rm \frac{t}{ha}}\times 1\;{\rm ha}=10\;{\rm t}.$$

The yield if the fertilizer is spread equally on both fields will be:
$$m=4.8\;{\rm \frac{t}{ha}}\times 1\;{\rm ha}+4.8\;{\rm \frac{t}{ha}}\times 1\;{\rm ha}=9.6\;{\rm t}.$$

Therefore, the farmer will produce more crops if he puts all fertilizer on one field.